# Can not use email library of CodeIgniter to send email to yahoo mail

Tags: codeigniter, email

I'm using CodeIgniter 2.1.3
I'm using mail library of CodeIgniter to send email.
As official document of CI. I use:

```
$this->load->library('email');

$this->email->from('info@mydomain.com', 'My Name');
$this->email->to('target@yahoo.com'); 

$this->email->subject('Email Test');
$this->email->message('Testing the email class.');  

$this->email->send();
```

When I use target(to) email is gmail such as target@gmail.com, every thing ok, I can receive email from CI. But when I use yahoo mail such as target@yahoo.com, target email can't receive email from CI send.

Any suggest?

PS:
I've checked my spam folder and it empty.
This is the output of print_debugger() method:

```
Your message has been successfully sent using the following protocol: mail
From: "Name" 
Return-Path: 
Reply-To: "info@mkvietnam.com" 
X-Sender: info@mkvietnam.com
X-Mailer: CodeIgniter
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
Message-ID: <51b06367996d8@mkvietnam.com>
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
=?utf-8?Q?Test_email?=
Email body
```

Comment: Did you check your SPAM folders ?

Comment: what are you getting in yahoo case by this method>>

echo $this->email->print_debugger();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the issue related to your hosting ip which may be blacklisted by YahooMail filter. You can check with testing in another hosting or by Googling

Comment: Exactly what I found! I've use other hosting is WebFaction. Everything ok. But with this code, the current hosting can not send to yahoo mail.